# How can i output desired element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am creating a route in node.js

and this is my code:

```
schedule.get('/conference/schedule_participants/:circle/:schedId', function(req, res) {
  if(req.schedId){
      getParticipants( req.params, function(contacts){
        results.contacts=contacts;
          res.json(contacts);
      }); 

  }else{
        res.json(contacts);
  }
});
```

the output in my browser is like this  :

```
[
{
"id":212,
"extenrealname":"UID1",
"name":"0090001513",
},
{
"id":214,
"extenrealname":"UID3",
"name":"0090001515",
},
]
```

How can i get **name** element so that my output will be like:

```
 [
    {
    "name":"0090001513",
    },
    {
    "name":"0090001515",
    },
    ]
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the input array to required array

```
var arr = [
    {
        "id": 212,
        "extenrealname": "UID1",
        "name": "0090001513"
    }, {
        "id": 214,
        "extenrealname": "UID3",
        "name": "0090001515"
    }
];
var output = arr.map( function(value){ return { name: value.name }; } );
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `map`:

```
schedule.get('/conference/schedule_participants/:circle/:schedId', function(req, res) {
  if(req.schedId){
      getParticipants( req.params, function(contacts){
          res.json(contacts.map(function(c) {
            return c.name;
          });
      }); 

  }else{
        res.json(contacts.map(function(c){ return c.name}));
  }
});
```